# How can I find the recently login history of itunes connect?

Tags: authentication, app-store-connect

My question is as the subject tells.

Cause I doubt that my the password of my itunes connect account has been leaked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You should contact the iTunes Connect support team. I'd recommend resetting your Apple ID's password and switch over to 2-factor authentication.

https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid#!&section=password
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152